# How to perform $lookup from different database in MongoDB + Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

What I am trying to achieve is pretty straightforward. I have a separate microservice with dedicated database for users and database for my app (everything is inside one MongoDB instance).

So, in my app I have comments, which have author field. So, I am trying to figure out how to put the information about author in that field, since the information about them is in another database and $lookup stage can't do this, because it is looking for a collection in the same database.

That being said, I could manually request an array of required users and then cycle throught comments, replacing the "author" field, but I hope there is a better solution.

As shown in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/supported-unsupported/pipeline/lookup-stage/), you can specify the "from" field for lookup stage in one of two ways:

1. String (collection name)
2. Map ({ db: 'db name', coll: 'collection name' })

The second option looks like what I needed, but Mongo driver for Go throws an error:

```
lookup_author := bson.D{
    {
        Key: "$lookup", Value: bson.D{
            {
                Key: "from", Value: bson.M{
                    "db":   "Auth",
                    "coll": "user",
                },
            },
            {
                Key: "localField", Value: "author_id",
            },
            {
                Key: "foreignField", Value: "_id",
            },
            {
                Key: "as", Value: "author",
            },
        },
    },
}
```

```
(AtlasError) Error getting from field in $lookup err=Expected 'from' to be string, but got primitive.D instead. Doc = [{from [{db Auth} {coll user}]} {localField author_id} {foreignField _id} {as author}]
```

So while it seems like this operation is possible, mongo driver for go just don't support it? Any other ways around? Or just do it manually?

Comment: As you've correctly linked to the documentation - the alternate syntax for `from` as `{db: <db>, coll: <collection-to-join>}` is only available for MongoDB **Atlas**. _"Or just do it manually?"_ - if you mean write the code to collect IDs from DB1 and then query DB2 separately with those IDs, then yes.

Comment: Yeah you've linked to the documentation for the command in [Atlas Data Federation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/data-federation/overview/). The documentation for the 'standard' one is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Answer (score 3):

You are right, mongoDB did introduce the feature of performing `$lookup` across different databases using a syntax that specifies both the database and the collection. But ***as far as I know*** this feature is specifically available in MongoDB Atlas Data Lake and not in regular MongoDB instances.

Comment: Ohh, thanks. So, what could be the solution for such case? :(

Comment: Are you going to merge large datasets? If they are not that consumptive, you can perform separate queries to each database and then manually combine the results in your code. There are some third party solutions like kafka, but unfortunately they will need more scaffolding and complicate your code.